# java alternative for phpMyAdmin

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, phpmyadmin

I find myself working in an environment where all I have access to is Tomcat + MySQL. No Apache, no PHP. I'm looking for a web interface to MySQL that will run under Tomcat (can't be a desktop interface, as the mysql port is not accessible).

I'm tried jMyAdmin and javaMyAdmin. I can't get either to work, and both lack documentation and community support. Can anyone make a recommendation please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to try [JSPMyAdmin](http://code.google.com/p/jsp-myadmin/).

Comment: Thanks. JSPMyAdmin has some warts, but it works. Thx again.

Comment: It should be noted that this project is no longer maintained (no surprise 5 years later)

Comment: Now there's jspMyAdmin2 which was still active Aug 2017: https://github.com/yugandhargangu/JspMyAdmin2

Answer (score -2):

Why not a normal client, like [squirrel](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/)?  Any of the desktop clients (like squirrel) should really do 99.99% of what you would want to do with phpmyadmin... why do you need something java-ish to run on the server?

Comment: Thx for your reply. As stated in my original post, it can't be a desktop interface, as the mysql port is not accessible.  The only port allowed to be open to my development environment is tomcat's. This is why I'm looking for something to run on the server.